# Accepted answer by an absent user is not sorted first

Tags: bug, migration, accepted-answer

[This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53262/change-to-text-console-using-ssh) was migrated after having received an accepted answer (not by the asker). Neither the asker nor the poster of the accepted answer have an account on the target site at this point. The accepted answer is not sorted before all other answers, as when an answer is self-accepted — which is not the case.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This specific instance "fixed itself" since zhenech registered on U&L. (I doubt this is site-specific though, maybe it should be reported on MSO?)

Comment: @Mat I encountered the behavior on U&L so I'm posting on its meta. I don't doubt that the issue is cross-site, but [posting on a child meta is absolutely fine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89228/which-meta-am-i-supposed-to-post-on/89232#89232).